# Column(Modifier = ..., () -> Unit): Unit' is deprecated. compose.web.web-widgets API is deprecated

Tags: compose-multiplatform, compose-web

When I start to learn compose multiplatform for WEB I faced the problem that **column is deprecated**. What use instead of it?

Comment: it seems the whole web-widgets module is deprecated and you have to build your own widgets...

Comment: I can't understand why they did it, it'd be so nice to have exactly the same code for Web, Desktop, Mobile, etc... :(